# Flutter adding some values to a list with Shared Preferences

Tags: flutter

I want to create a ToDo application. I input the task into textField and saved the task with setString and get it with getString and add it to my list but when I input new task to textField, my previous value is missing and only my new value is appearing. How can I solve this problem ?

My getString;

```
class TodoListState extends State<TodoList> {
  List<String> _todoItems = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getLocalData();
  }

  Future getLocalData() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() => _todoItems.add(preferences.getString("key")));
  }
```

my setString;

```
body: Column(children: [
          TextField(
            controller: itemcontroller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: " your task ",
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("save the data"),
            onPressed: () {
              savetask().then((value) {
                Navigator.push(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TodoApp()));
              });
            },
          ),
        ]));
  }

  Future savetask() async {
    /* liste.add(itemcontroller.text); */
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await preferences.setString("key", itemcontroller.text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what you are doing:

You start by getting whatever is on the SharedPreferences. For the sake of example, lets start with nothing. Then, you input a value into the TextField. After you press the button, a String is saved on your SharedPreferences. After that, you enter another task, and by saving that value you will override the key that you are using.

So, what should you do?
Add the task that you submitted to the list, and only then you save that same list to the SharedPreferences.

Therefore, you should do this:

```dart
void savetask() async {
    _todoItems.add(itemcontroller.text);
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await preferences.setString("key", _todoItems.toString());
  }
```

But beware! SharedPreferences does not support Lists! It saves it as a String. That makes me recommend that you use [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite), in order to persist information. But that decision is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Actually I have two different classes. my _todoItems is in first class. How can I pass _todoItems to the second class? and I know that sqflite is used generally for big data  but I think my data is small

Answer (score 0):

I can see what is the problem.

The SharedPreferences is a wrapper for sharePreference store api in Android and UsersDefaults for iOS. Both apis only store certain types of simple data in a key, value scheme into files.

Here are the documentation for the two apis:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences?hl=es-419

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults

An here the documentation for the flutter plugin :

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

About your issue, the value is the same because you are storing the data with the same key. ("key")

You are always overriding the same value for the same key. To store all task you must use different keys foreach save.

You need to use the methods: getStringList() and setStringList()

Here are one example how you can modify the getLocalData():

```
Future getLocalData() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    setState((){ 
     
      _todoItems.clear();
      _todoItems.addAll(preferences.getStringList("key"));
});

}
```

And here the saveTask method :

```
Future savetask() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var list = prefereces.getStringList("key");
    list.add(itemcontroller.text);
    await preferences.setStringList("key", list);
  }
}
```

I hope this solutions and comments can help with your challenge.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment too. I copy paste what you wrote for getLocalData and there was no any error but how can you use two items in getStringList.   var list = prefereces.getStringList("key", itemcontroller.text);   there is an error.

Comment: @Timurturbil Sorry i did a mistake in wrote the code i fixed it.

Comment: it didn't work again the error is _TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<Object>')  Can I share all of my project with you